# Apex : your session has expired

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an apex application.

When the user subscribes,he receives a mail to validate his account. In the mail there is a link he has to click on. Once the user clicks on the links he is redirected to a page in my application that validates his account.

This scheme works perfectly.

However when the user tries to submit new things (basically logs in) I get the error message : Your session has expired.

It seems like, when he subscribes, my app creates a session. And when he clicks the link on the email, the app creates a new session id.

Is there any way to clear all the caches when loading the login page please ?

I tried the solution here but it's not working : https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_ses_val.htm#BEIHCICF

I still get the same error : Your session has expired.

Any ideas please ?

Thanks.

Comment: voting to close : "**too broad** Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question." StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,    https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck

Comment: Please show an example of the link as it is given in an email. I'll be interested to see what, if any, session ID you're putting in the email. Also, please post exactly which version of APEX you're using.